# Failed to resolve a path when in Docker Overlay2 environment

Tags: docker, centos7, esxi

I've a problem with Docker Overlay2. After the export of a VM in ESXi with CentOS 7 OS I encountered this error

***(dm-0): Metadata CRC error detected at xfs_allocbt_read_verify...***[dm-0 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYUXB.png)

and I've solved with *xfs_repair /dev/dm-0* command. When I start the OS I've these errors

***overlayfs: failed to resolve /var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/...***[overlay2 errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHk6a.png).

I've stopped docker and updated */etc/docker/daemon.json* file with  *"storage-driver": "overlay2"* but when I start docker and check the status, the errors persists.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include the text of any errors and inputs in the body of your question. Links should be used for supporting details, but the question should still make sense when the links break.

Comment: Also posted on https://forums.docker.com/t/failed-to-resolve-a-path-when-in-docker-overlay2-environment/123236